# Write ClientSide code from Custom ASP .NET Extender server side ExtenderControlBase

Tags: asp.net

I'm extending **ExtenderControlBase** control in ASP .NET. It's called:

```
public class LookupExtender : ExtenderControlBase
```

Basically what it doest in something similar to autocomplete function - but static. LookupExtender has **TypeName** & **ListName** attritbutes that specify:

- class that has **string[] GetList(string listName)** method
- name of the list that will be passed to GetList method

And now, LookupExtender creates **TypeName** instance on the fly (reflection), calls **GetList** method and I would like to render **string[]** result to client side as array, so that extender client-side code has static source for autosuggestion.

Is there any way to render JavaScript from **LookupExtender** class?

This is my sample code (currently autosuggestion values are hardcoded):

```
set_TargetTextBoxID: function (value) {
    this._targetTextBoxID = value;

    $(function () {
        var availableTags = [
            "Switzerland",
            "Poland",
            "Europe",
            "USA",
            "Asia"
        ];
        $("#" + value).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength: 0,
            close: function () {
                $(this).blur();
            }
        }).focus(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be pretty easy

- server side of extender:

  ```
  protected override void RenderInnerScript(ScriptBehaviorDescriptor descriptor)
  {
      var listSource = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(SourceType) as ILookupExtenderListSource;
      if (listSource == null) return;

      var lookupList = listSource.GetList(SourceList);
      descriptor.AddProperty("LookupArray", lookupList);
  }
  ```
- client side js script:

CIPNet.Extenders.LookupBehavior.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {
        CIPNet.Extenders.LookupBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
    },

```
dispose: function() {
    CIPNet.Extenders.LookupBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
},

//
// Property accessors 
//

get_LookupArray: function() {
    return this._lookupArray;
},

set_LookupArray: function(value) {
    this._lookupArray = value;
},

get_TargetTextBoxID: function() {
    return this._targetTextBoxID;
},

set_TargetTextBoxID: function(value) {
    this._targetTextBoxID = value;
    var that = this;

    $(function() {

        var showSuggestion = function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        };

        var availableTags = that._lookupArray;
        $("#" + value).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0
        }).click(showSuggestion);
    });
}
```

};